# Am I missing a package?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written the following code so far:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request,response) { 
    homeRoute(request, response);
}).listen(1337);
console.log('Server running at http://<Dans-Laptop>/');

function homeRoute(request, response) {
        //response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        //response.write('Header\n');
        //response.write('Search\n');
        //response.end('Footer\n');

//response.end('Hello world\n');
//if url == "/" && POST
//redirect to /:username
```

The problem I'm having is that as soon as I enter "function homeRoute(request, response) { and run the Server.js file from the CMD I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token > at exports.runInThisContext etc..

If I blank out that line using // everything up until there is working fine i.e the server starts running at http:///

What is the problem with the last bit of code? Am I missing a package?

Comment: That code throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`. Try providing a test case that actually demonstrates your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The error im receiving now is: throw er; // unhandled 'error' event

Comment: var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request,response) { 
 homeRoute(request, response);
 }).listen(1337);
 console.log('Server running at http://<Dans-Laptop>/');

 function homeRoute(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write('Header\n');
  response.write('Search\n');
  response.end('Footer\n'); 
 }

Comment: Edit the question, don't splurge an unreadable mass of code into a comment.

Comment: I have sorted it, thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Please don't add your text editor to the tags, it has no relevance to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this query.. changed the port to 3000 and it appears to be fine!

Thanks.